# creating a table in excel using python

Tags: python, xlwt

I am using xlwt to write to cells in excel from python. I am wondering if there is some way to select the written cells and insert a table. I have references to the cell range. Please help out.

Comment: Kindly show us what you've tried so far?Until then,we won't be able to help you

Comment: Also, any samples of what data you have and how you want it to appear in excel would help clarify the question.

Comment: @shaktimaan: I imported the xlwt module and wrote values to cells in an Excel worksheet, like this: ws.write(0,0,'name'). Suppose the range of written cells is A1:C10, is it possible to insert a table for those cells alone?

Comment: @Sologoub: I have numbers in all the cells. I want them to appear as a table (like when you select a range of cells and go insert->table from the menu ribbon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I m not aware of xlwt. But you can try it using xlsxwriter.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_tables.html